Help identify this horror movie about black mouth tentacles that infect other people?
This was a movie that I saw long ago and I really want to see it again but I just can't remember what its name was, not even the website for finding movies would help. I'll try to add as many details as possible. 
The movie was definitely made somewhere between 2007 and 2000,not animated, it's likely made in the USA
It's about a team of people armed with pistols and earpieces who go on some kind of mission to investigate a tentacle disease or something, it works like: If someone has this disease, they can shoot (black) tentacles out their mouth or something and wrap them around their victim to infect them too, you also can't tell if they're infected or not until you learn it the hard way. 
The team consisted of one or two women, one black guy with a bald head, one technician who tries to fix the elevator and some cowboy-dressed guy. 
It's an English speaking movie, I can barely remember any of the actors' names because it was such a long time ago (10 years or so). 
How the characters get infected: The "cowboy" gets into a standoff with another cowboy, he wins but the loser turns out to be infected. The technician at the elevator sees some blonde woman in the hallway walking towards him wearing a sparkling white dress, he follows her to a dark room lit by a standing torch and she's wearing a purple/black dress, she seduces the technician and infects him with the tentacles. The technician looked a bit like Nick Zano when he acted in Final Destination.
After the technician got infected, the black guy goes over to the technician to check on him to see how he's doing (He does not know that he was infected), the technician makes it seem like he's fixing the elevator and then tests it in front of the African-american team member, when the elevator doors close and open, he does not see the technician anywhere, only for him to come back in tentacle form. The black guy shoots at him a few times but to no avail and then gets wrapped by the tentacles.
The movie ends with only 3 survivors being two Caucasian men and a woman, one of these men are in a relationship with the woman. The surviving team members leave on a ship of some sort that travels on water, I believe.  There was a stripping scene with the blonde.

Gee, I wonder this movie will ever be found, I remember the cutscenes so vividly in my head. If I could place a bounty on this question, I would, it's all I need.

OK so here's an update; so far I've found out that the movie is a cross between Ghost Ship (2002) for the similar story and Deep Rising (1998) for the tentacles.

The movie name is: The Thing Below I got you covered. I had to re-read the description a bit, but I happened to see this movie and though cheesy, it was a decent watch!
Trailer linked:




Can you write what are the similarities with the description in the question? We should be able to read in your answer in case the link  breaks.

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume some of the details you have about the movie are incorrect. I think the movie you are describing is 'Ghost Ship', which fits the time frame (2002), it's not animated.
The synopsis (from the prior link):

After discovering a passenger ship missing since 1962 floating adrift on the Bering Sea, salvagers claim the vessel as their own. Once they begin towing the ghost ship towards harbor, a series of bizarre ocurrences happen and the group becomes trapped inside the ship, which they soon learn is inhabited by a demonic creature.

It has a crew, one of which is a black bald man:

He gets seduced by a woman who tricks him into falling down an elevator shaft. 

It's primarily about ghosts and one in particular who is attempting to 'collect souls'.  There aren't tentacles, per say, but there is a spreading black tissue at some points..
Here's the trailer: Ghost Ship

Ok good! The movie was somewhat similar to the one that you are talking about, except that the woman trying to seduce was blonde, and was seducing a technician or repairman trying to fix an elevator.

Hm, it almost fits. I think there's a blonde woman in it too, but she doesn't seduce anyone into falling down an elevator shaft.

Not to falling down a shaft though, first the blonde leads the technician to a dark room lit by nothing but a torch, and then strips to seduce him to get close enough to infect him
